# What are the best practices for Kiln repositories?

Tags: kiln

I noticed in [this image](http://fogcreek.com/Kiln/i/en-US/LearnMore/CodeOrganization.png) from the Kiln site that the repositories are named stable, qa and devel. Is there any reasoning behind this? Or is there a better/different way that's more accepted?

Comment: The Kiln Stackexchange site has been shut down & replaced by help documentation on their main website. The [help page on this subject](http://help.fogcreek.com/8800/repository-design-suggestions) describes 2 structures, one more appropriate for applications that have a single live version (e.g. web-based), and another structure which is appropriate for applications that may have multiple versions live in the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a [read of this post](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/500/should-i-use-more-than-one-repository/504#504) on the [Kiln StackExchange](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/) site which explains why they use stable and devel. It also suggests other ways of structuring your repositories.

> We keep a devel and stable repository.
>   New features go into devel and
>   eventually get merged forward to
>   stable, while bug fixes go into stable
>   and get merged back into devel.